# Debug assertion failed: Subscript out of range with std::vector

Tags: c++, stdstring, stdlist

I'm trying to fix this problem which seems like I am accessing at an out of range index, but VS fails to stop where the error occurred leaving me confused about what's causing this.

**The Error:**

> Debug Assertion Failed! Program: .... File: c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector Line: 1440 Expression: String subscript out of range

**What the program does:**

There are two threads:

**Thread 1:**

The first thread looks (amongst other things) for changes in the current window using `GetForegroundWindow()`, the check happens not on a loop but when a `WH_MOUSE_LL` event is triggered. The data is split into structs of fixed size so that it can be sent to a server over tcp. The first thread and records the data (Window Title) into an `std::list` in the current struct.

```
if(change_in_window)
{
    GetWindowTextW(hActWin,wTitle,256);
    std::wstring title(wTitle);
    current_struct->titles.push_back(title);
}
```

**Thread 2:**

The second thread is called looks for structs not send yet, and it puts their content into `char` buffers so that they can be sent over tcp. While I do not know exactly where the error is, looking from the type of error it was to do either with a string or a list, and this is the only code from my whole application using lists/strings (rest are conventional arrays). Also commenting the if block as mentioned in the code comments stops the error from happening.

```
  BOOL SendStruct(DATABLOCK data_block,bool sycn)
    {
    [..]

                int _size = 0;
// Important note, when this if block is commented the error ceases to exist, so it has something to do with the following block
                if(!data_block.titles.empty()) //check if std::list is empty
                {

                    for (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator itr  = data_block.titles.begin(); itr != data_block.titles.end() ; itr++) {
                        _size += (((*itr).size()+1) * 2); 
                    } //calculate size required. Note the +1 is for an extra character between every title
                    wchar_t* wnd_wbuffer = new wchar_t[_size/2](); //allocate space
                    int _last = 0;
    //loop through every string and every char of a string and write them down
                    for (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator itr = data_block.titles.begin(); itr != data_block.titles.end(); itr++)
                    {
                        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= (itr->size()-1); i++)
                        {

                            wnd_wbuffer[i+_last] = (*itr)[i] ;
                        }
                        wnd_wbuffer[_last+itr->size()] = 0x00A6; // separator
                        _last += itr->size()+1;
                    }

                    unsigned char* wnd_buffer = new unsigned char[_size];
                    wnd_buffer = (unsigned char*)wnd_wbuffer;
                    h_io->header_w_size = _size;
                    h_io->header_io_wnd = 1;
                    Connect(mode,*header,conn,buffer_in_bytes,wnd_buffer,_size);
                    delete wnd_wbuffer;
                }
                else
            [..]
                return true;
            }
```

**My attempt at thread synchronization:** 
There is a pointer to the first data_block created (db_main)
pointer to the current data_block  (db_cur)

```
//datablock format
    typedef struct _DATABLOCK
        {
            [..]
            int logs[512];
            std::list<std::wstring> titles;
            bool bPrsd; // has this datablock been sent true/false
            bool bFull; // is logs[512] full true/false
            [..]
            struct _DATABLOCK *next;
        } DATABLOCK;    


//This is what thread 1 does when it needs to register a mouse press and it is called like this:
    if(change_in_window)
    {
        GetWindowTextW(hActWin,wTitle,256);
        std::wstring title(wTitle);
        current_struct->titles.push_back(title);
    }
    RegisterMousePress(args);
    [..]
//pseudo-code to simplify things , although original function does the exact same thing. 
    RegisterMousePress()
        {
            if(it_is_full)
            {
                db_cur->bFull= true;
                if(does db_main exist)
                {
                    db_main = new DATABLOCK;
                    db_main = db_cur;
                    db_main->next = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    db_cur->next = new DATABLOCK;
                    db_cur = db_cur->next;
                    db_cur->next = NULL;

                }
                SetEvent(eProcessed); //tell thread 2 there is at least one datablock ready
            }
            else
            {
            write_to_it();
            }
        }
//this is actual code and entry point of thread 2 and my attempy at synchronization
    DWORD WINAPI InitQueueThread(void* Param)
    {
        DWORD rc;
        DATABLOCK* k;
        SockWClient writer;
        k = db_main;
        while(true)
        {
            rc=WaitForSingleObject(eProcessed,INFINITE);
            if (rc== WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {   
                do
                {
                    if(k->bPrsd)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        if(!k)
                        {break;}
                        k->bPrsd = TRUE;
    #ifdef DEBUG_NET
                        SendStruct(...);
    #endif

                    }
                    if(k->next == NULL || k->next->bPrsd ==TRUE || !(k->next->bFull))
                    {
                        ResetEvent(eProcessed);
                        break;
                    }

                } while (k = k->next); // next element after each loop
            }
        }
        return 1;

    }
```

**Details:**

Now something makes me believe that the error is not in there, because the substring error is very rare. I have been only able to reproduce it with 100% chance when pressing Mouse_Down+Wnd+Tab to scroll through windows and keeping it pressed for some time (while it certainly happened on other cases as well). I avoid posting the whole code because it's a bit large and confusion is unavoidable. If the error is not here I will edit the post and add more code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do have some sort of synchronization of your list object? Because I cannot see anything in your code.

Comment: You mean avoiding the object to be accessed by both threads at the same time?

Comment: More like both threads changing the object at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any thread synchronization here. If one thread reads from the structure while the other writes, it might be read during initialization, with a non-empty list containing an empty string (or something invalid, in between).

If there isn't a mutex or semaphore outside the posted function, that is likely the problem.

All the size calculations appear to be valid for Windows, although I didn't attempt to run it… and `<= … -1` instead of `<` in  `i <= (itr->size()-1)` and `2` instead of `sizeof (wchar_t)` in  `new wchar_t[_size/2]();` are a bit odd.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have edited the question and added details of my attempt at synchronization you may want to look at them

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that while thread 2 correctly waits for the data and thread 1 correctly notifies about them, thread 2 doesn't prevent thread 1 from doing anything with them under its hands while it still process the data. The typical device used to solve such problem is the monitor pattern.

It consist of one mutex (used to protect the data, held anytime you access them) and a condition variable (=Event in Windows terms), which will convey the information about new data to the consumer.

The producer would normally obtain the mutex, produce the data, release the mutex, then fire the event.

The consumer is more tricky - it has to obtain the mutex, check if new data hasn't become available, then wait for the Event using the SignalObjectAndWait function that temporarily releases the mutex, then process newly acquired data, then release the mutex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to apply what you suggested but I'm unsure about how to this using windows threading. I know that I need to call `CreateMutex` to create a mutex and release it using `ReleaseMutex`, but how do I 'obtain' it? Also what should I call `SignalObjectAndWait` with, what do I wait for and what do I signal?